git: determine if repo was cloned blobless or treeless
I want a programmatic way (preferably an alias) to determine whether a repository was cloned with either --filter=blob:none or --filter=tree:0, and to be able to tell which.
eg:
if git is-treeless; then echo "repo is treeless"; fi

How would I go about that?

In a blobless/treeless clone I see these keys in .git/config:
[remote "origin"]
    promisor = true
    partialclonefilter = combine:blob:none+tree:0

So you can try
$ git config remote.origin.promisor
true

$ git config remote.origin.partialclonefilter
combine:blob:none+tree:0

If you have many remotes perhaps you need to loop over them until you find a promisor remote.
The docs.
Upd. shell code to check if the remote is promisor:
test "`git config remote.origin.promisor`" = true

Shell code to check if the clone is blobless, treeless or both:
git config remote.origin.partialclonefilter | grep -Fq blob
git config remote.origin.partialclonefilter | grep -Fq tree
git config remote.origin.partialclonefilter | grep -q 'blob.*tree'


I'm trying to work out if its a blobless vs treeless, and I can't see this addressed in your aswer.  If blobless, I'm ok, if treeless, I'll likely need to clone again as filling in for missing blobs in a treeless clone takes forever.
